# why to use bind or on instead of direct event triggers in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have seen many people use bind or on functions instead of direct event triggers etc

```
  $(document).bind('click', function(){
        alert('Fired');
    });
```

instead of

```
  $(document).click(function(){
alert('Fired');
 });
```

same thing for on function

```
$('p').on('click', function()({
alert('fired');
 });
```

instead of

```
 $('p').click(function()({
  alert('fired');
 });
```

can someone explain it?

Comment: They are all the exact same thing, however, `.on()` is used in favor of `.live()`, `.bind()`, and `.delegate()` as any nuances and bugs that exists between the aforementioned have been fixed and merged to perform as intended. Also, there is no direct benefit of using `.on()` as opposed to `.click()` if the element exists at page load, and you are delegating the event within the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Checkout the docs for http://api.jquery.com/click/ , http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and http://api.jquery.com/on/ , they all mention which method is preferred and which one is a short-cut for another and so on. Basically, use `bind()` if on jquery 1.6-, use `delegate()` if on jquery 1.6- and need binding events to dynamic elements and use `on()` if jquery 1.7+ for static and binding to dynamic elements using delegation.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

`.click()` is a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`. There is no difference at all. So you might as well stick to `.on()` and save that extra function call.

[jQuery documentation for .bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()` methods have been superseded by `.on()`. These functions are going to be removed in future versions of jQuery. The `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Internally, jQuery maps all these methods and shorthand event handler setters to the `.on()` method, further indicating that you should ignore these methods from now on and just use `.on()`:

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
},
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use .bind or .on just about everywhere I can. I almost never use .click. Here's why:

If you want to make your website or web app cross-platform compatible, and you want the user to "click" a button if they are on a computer and to "tap" a button on an iPad or other mobile device, .click may not be good for you.

I use something like this:

```
$("#myButton").on(inputType(), functionHandler(){console.log("you have clicked or touched myButton!"});

function inputType(){
    if(getUserDevice != "computer"){
        return "touchend";
    }else{
        return "click";
    }
}

function getUserDevice(){
    //code in here determine if it's a computer or a "touch device"
    //return "computer";
}
```